# External access settings for Office 365 groups

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to update GroupSettings of individual O365 Group, however I always get error

```
Resource 'guid' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
```

A code I'm using to update the group settings

```
var graphResult = graphClient.GroupSettings[guid].Request().UpdateAsync(groupSetting).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I've tried to use Group guid as well as GroupSettings guid, none of that worked.

I can set the settings for the first time (overwrite defaults) using codde below, but update doesn't work afterwards.

```
graphResult = graphClient.Groups[guid].Settings.Request().AddAsync(groupSetting).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Any idea what can be wrong please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since documentation doesn't say how to update settings for particular group, here it is: you need to use both IDs in call

```
graphResult = graphClient.Groups[groupGuid].Settings[settingsGuid].Request().UpdateAsync(groupSetting)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use GroupSettings guid here.

I can repro your issue when I use an incorrect guid here.

You should firstly use `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groupSettings` to find the GroupSettings guid of the GroupSetting you want to update.

Please note that you should include all the values in the request body even though you don't want to update some of them.

Then you could put it as the guid in your code.

It's stronly recommended to have a quick test in [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

Comment: Thanks Allen, of course I've checked documentation and graph, unfortunately this case was not covered in documentation and hence not clear.
Anyway, it's resolved now.

Comment: @MarekBuban. If my answer doesn't help, could you share your solution here? You can post a new answer and accespt it as the answer of this post.